# Mongoose query very slow (basically never returning) but works in mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This it the query built by mongoose

```
myCollection.find({ recipient: 'thisIsALongString' }, { sort: { date: -1 },   limit: 1000, skip: 90000, fields: {} })
```

When I run this from my node app, it basically never resolves.  I have waited as long as an hour.

The same query performs fine on some collections, or on different fields from this collection.  For example, this returns in seconds:

```
myCollection.find({ sender: 'thisIsALongString' }, { sort: { date: -1 },   limit: 1000, skip: 90000, fields: {} })
```

In the mongo shell, what appears to be the same query executes pretty quickly, again in seconds:

```
db.myCollection.find({"recipient":"thisIsALongString"}).limit(5000).skip(90000).sort({"date": -1}).toArray()
```

What on earth could be going on?

Comment: I think problem not with mongodb and it's driver, I think problem with nodejs code. Seems like You've forgot to handle result or error properly or maybe problem is somewhere else. Can You share app code completely to understand where it breaks?

Comment: also have You indexed `recipient` attribute?

Comment: Thanks num8er - I went back through the code and you were right I had a missing .catch() that allowed me to log the error (which was a timeout).

Comment: I've increased the mongoose timeouts and everything works as expected.

Comment: please write Your solution in answer to Your issue to share with people solution